# Error While Inserting large amount of data using Insert statement in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert records into table have large amount of data

**File Description:**

```
Size : 65.0 MB
Records count : 10000
```

**My Sample Data:**

```
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO
.......
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO
INSERT INTO tbldata(col1,col2,col3)values(col1,col2,col3)
GO 
.......
UPTO 10000 ROWS
```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.(mscorlib)
```

**I Tried:**
[I verified this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1795074/inserting-1000s-of-rows-to-sql-table-using-ssms)

Under SQL Server\Properties\Memory there is a setting for Minimum Memory Per Query. you can raise this number temporarily to help increase the number of records between the GO statements. In my case I raised this to 5000 (10000 caused a system out of memory error, not good) so I settled for 5000, after a few tests I found that I could now import about 20,000 rows so I placed a GO statement every 20,000 rows (took about 10 minutes) and I was able to import over 200,000 rows in one query.

Comment: this may help you http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75326/management-studio-system-outofmemoryexception

Comment: How are you inserting the rows? Are you opening the script in SQL Server Management Studio?. Are you inserting the rows by code?. System.OutOfMemoryException is a CLR exception, so I guess you are using SQL Server Management Studio, in that case you should try sqlcmd command line tool.

Comment: I don't know about sqlcmd command line tool. Can you send me link about that tool @Jesus Lopez.

Comment: @Dinesh alla, Google is your friend

Answer (score 0):

The maximum batch size for SQL Server 2005 is 65,536 * Network Packet Size (NPS), where NPS is usually 4KB. That works out to 256 MB. That would mean that your insert statements would average 5.8 KB each. That doesn't seem right, but maybe there are extraneous spaces or something unusual in there.

My first suggestion would be to put a "GO" statement after every INSERT statement. This will break your single batch of 45,000 INSERT statements into 45,000 separate batches. This should be easier to digest. Be careful, if one of those inserts fails you may have a hard time finding the culprit. You might want to protect yourself with a transaction. You can add those statements quickly if your editor has a good search-and-replace (that will let you search on and replace return characters like \r\n) or a macro facility.

The second suggestion is to use a Wizard to import the data straight from Excel. The wizard builds a little SSIS package for you, behind the scenes, and then runs that. It won't have this problem

reference got from this [Out of memory exception](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16763/how-do-i-run-a-large-script-with-many-inserts-without-running-out-of-memory)

Comment: @Dineshalla yup didnt check your update ... why you dont try `SSIS` to insert the file